# javascript window open passing dynamic url parameters

Tags: javascript, window.open, dynamic-url

Working in ColdFusion, I have a javascript function like this:

```
function switchyn(obj,id,karr,kval){
  ... some stuff about obj and id ....
  var fullurl = 'arch-update.cfm?karr='+karr+'&kval='+kval;
  window.open(fullurl);
 }
```

The window opens fine, but the parameters passed to it are "karr" and "kval"; what I want to pass are the values of karr and kval.  I can't figure out how to do that, and can't find any information in an online search.  Can this be done?  And if so, how?

OKAY, I solved it.  When I switched the single quote to double quotes in fullurl, the right thing is happening.

```
var fullurl = "arch-update.cfm?karr="+karr+"&kval="+kval;
```

It seems strange that single quotes don't work and double quotes do; and it seems stranger that I can find no reference to that anywhere.

Comment: Please include how you are calling `switchyn`

Comment: Could you also add what type or sample data for `karr` and `kval`? Ideally what you are doing should have worked. What URL do you see in newly opened window?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the `karr` thing and `kval` thing as strings

`switchyn(object, id, 'karr', 'kval')`

I don't actually know what you want to do but i hope that's useful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).